# having trouble compiling shader for vulkan with shaderc

Tags: c++, vulkan, shaderc

i am trying to create a shader for Vulkan using shaderc but when compiling the fragment shader i get the `error: '' : unexpected token`.

here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

layout(push_constant) uniform Material
{
    vec4 u_Color;
} u_MaterialUniforms;


void main()
{
    color = u_MaterialUniforms.u_Color;
}
```

and here is the code for compiling it:

```
shaderc::Compiler compiler;
shaderc::CompileOptions options;
options.SetTargetEnvironment(shaderc_target_env_vulkan, shaderc_env_version_vulkan_1_2);
const bool optimize = true;
if (optimize) {
  options.SetOptimizationLevel(shaderc_optimization_level_performance);
}
shaderc::SpvCompilationResult module = compiler.CompileGlslToSpv(source, shaderc_glsl_fragment_shader, FilePath.c_str(), options);
if (module.GetCompilationStatus() != shaderc_compilation_status_success)
{
  AE_ASSERT(false, module.GetErrorMessage());
}
```

The vertex shader works and compiles. I tried simplifying the fragment shader so it uses a static color but that did not work and gave the same error. I am not sure where to start trouble shooting to find the bug.

Comment: Shader compiles fine with glslangValidator, so it's either a shaderc bug or you have some weird characters or string corruption when you load it.

Comment: I also got same situation where its giving this unexpected token error and it compiles with glslc.exe. Any update on this by any chance?

Comment: I found I was reading the file wrong and it was storing multiple null termination characters